# Paypal standard does not show as payment for users ( it is enabled )

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, paypal

Paypal standard does not show as payment  for users ( it is enabled ). I saw something one of the Patch Notes that  it was a fix  for  Paypal not showing on checkout  for certain merchant countries , in this case is about Romania.

Comment: How is it configured? Did you try with other contries?

Comment: I tried with italy and euro as for test it didn't show either

Comment: OK , after retesting changed the currency while the paypal standard was disable and  after changing the currency i re-enable it  it worked, so definetly currency related issue

Answer (score 5):

Create the file Config.php in /app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

Step 1

Copy the file from /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

Step 2

Look for the $_supportedCurrencyCodes

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

and add your currency that needs supporting to the end of the array

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'PHP');
```

Source : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use paypal standard with RON (Ro currency). Not out of the box anyway.
Here is why:

before displaying the allowed payment methods magento calls the method `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container::_canUseMethod`. This methods checks if you can use the payment method. Among other conditions there is also this:

```
    if (!$method->canUseForCurrency($this->getQuote()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode())) {
        return false;
    }
```

And if you take a look at the method `Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard::canUseForCurrency` it will check to see this:

```
public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
{
    return $this->getConfig()->isCurrencyCodeSupported($currencyCode);
}
```

Going deeper inside the `Mage_Paypal_Model_Config` you will find the supported currencies:

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

`RON` is not among them

Comment: Thanks  for the detailed answer Marius, so basicly  there is no way around it ? by modifying the code to support RON aswell ? or i missunderstood?

Comment: The supported currencies are there for a reason. If you add RON to them you might get errors. A workaround would be to have your base currency in EUR (or any other supported currency) and just display the prices in RON. But this might generate other issues regarding the prices.