# Paypal payment gateway

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I got a error if i use Pay pal

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported
>   (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See
>   additional error messages for details)

Comment: Which currency is used?

Comment: Indian Currency

Answer (score 1):

credits : @Boogz

Create the file Config.php in */app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php*

Step 1

Copy the file from */app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php* to */app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php*

Step 2

Look for the $_supportedCurrencyCodes

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

and add your currency that needs supporting to the end of the array

I assume INR is indian currency.

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'INR');
```

Source : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency

Comment: No Still same error

Comment: yes INR : 1.0000 USD:0.0157

Comment: are you using INR as base currency ?

Comment: Where i need to check

Comment: when you go for `system > configuration > general > currency set up` , what currency you set as base currency ?

Comment: Yes Indian Rupee only

Comment: change to US dollar and check whether its working or not ?

Comment: US Doller is Working but pricing is problem it show usd amount not rupees

Comment: this solution should work as mentioned [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30534/paypal-standard-does-not-show-as-payment-for-users-it-is-enabled) . is this multi store site or only single ?

Comment: Not Multistore its Single Store

Comment: Since Indian Rupee is not support by paypal (and not only the module). You can ask Paypal to support indian rupee.

Comment: @MagentoDev try this extension in demo site & check : https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

Comment: @BabyinMagento thanks i will check and let you know

Comment: @MagentoDev did you found solution, if so please accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/#paypal the indian currency is not supported by paypal.

Comment: Okay how to fix this ?